# Can $\sin(x)$ be written as the product of its infinite roots $(0,\pi,-\pi..)$ as - $\sin(x)=(x)(x+\pi)(x-\pi)(x+2\pi)(x-2\pi)..$

Tags: calculus

My Question is that can $\sin(x)$ be written as the product of its infinite roots as -
$$\sin(x)=(x)(x+\pi)(x-\pi)(x+2\pi)(x-2\pi)...$$

I have already seen in many places $ \sin(x)$ being written as-
$$\sin(x) =  x\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$

And then using this result to prove Basel problem,but moreover the factorization I have written above can also be easily used to prove Basel problem using similar process as that used originally .

So does this mean that the factorization given above is correct ?Because that does seem more intuitive to me even though I don't have a formal proof of it at hand nor any statement/result which claims that writing - 
$$\sin(x)=(x)(x+\pi)(x-\pi)(x+2\pi)(x-2\pi)...$$

Is simply very wrong.

Comment: It's not enough to write an infinite product that has the right zeros; that infinite product needs to converge. The second formula that you've seen elsewhere does converge for all $x$; the first formula which you're proposing doesn't converge for any $x$ (except the multiples of $\pi$ themselves where it vanishes).

Comment: Let x = $\frac{pi}{2}$ Then sin(pi/2) = 1 but RHS = pi/2 *$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(pi/2+n*pi\right)\left(pi/2-n*pi\right) $ which goes up to complexInfinity. Therefore LHS $\neq$ RHS. One can use wolfram mathematics to check my statement

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the finite product$$ x\prod_{n=1}^p \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)=x\prod_{n=1}^p \left(\frac{n^2\pi^2-x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)=x\prod_{n=1}^p\left(\frac{(-1)(x-n\pi)(x+n\pi)}{n^2\pi^2}\right)=(-1)^p x\frac{\prod_{n=1}^p (x-n\pi)(x+n\pi) }{\prod_{n=1}^p n^2\pi^2 }=(-1)^p x \frac{\prod_{n=1}^p (x-n\pi)(x+n\pi) }{\pi^{2p} (p!)^2 }=\frac{(-1)^p}{\pi^{2p} (p!)^2  }x{\prod_{n=1}^p (x-n\pi)(x+n\pi) }$$

Answer (score 0):

you need to write it as $$\sin(x)=Ax(x-\pi)(x+\pi)(x-2\pi)(x+2\pi)\cdots$$
and the value of $A$ (note $A$ is not a constant in fact its tending to $0$) can be obtained from  the expression you have provided 
now differentiating and substituting $x=0$ we get 
$$cos(0)=1=A(-\pi)(\pi)(-2\pi)(2\pi)\cdots$$ thus we can say $$A=-\frac{1}{\pi^2}.-\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\cdots$$ now substitute respective fractions to obtain the equation you have specified in your problem

Comment: can you give a hint on how to find value of $A$ ?

Comment: hint: $\frac{d}{dx}\sin{x}$ and substitute $x=0$ @Freelancer

Comment: @Freelancer see the edit i hope it makes things clearer

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 i have not mentioned A is a constant ,